# need help to config mvc routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a logs table for users, and want to extract records by `userId` and datetime parameters.
How can I create route config so that my urls can be such as:

> Logs/userid/
>
> Logs/userid/year/
>
> Logs/userid/year/month/
>
> Logs/userid/year/month/day/

and my action method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Read(int? userId, int? year, int? month, int? day)
{

}
```

Necessarily i do not want just one route, if their is a solution with some routes i appreciate it, but i want my action method's syntax could like above if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when userid and month are provided, but not year or day? What does your URL look like then?

Comment: if month provided, userid and year can not be omitted. and if day is provided all other paramters must be provided. this is a search view. i want it to flexible.

Comment: What's wrong with doing this: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Logs",
            url: "logs/{user}/{year}/{month}/{day}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Logs", action = "Details", user = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional, month = UrlParameter.Optional, day = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: @ganders try it, it won't work. Only the last parameter in a route can be optional. The route in your comment is valid, but it cannot make year and month nullable `int`s, only day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last parameter in a route can be optional. I suggest you do your route like this:

```
Logs/{userid}
```

... and use querystring for the rest of the parameters.

```
Logs/{userid}?year=2014&month=1&day=20
```

Alternatively, you could pass in the whole date as an optional string and then parse it in the action:

```
Logs/{userId}/{date?}
Logs/{userId}/2014
Logs/{userId}/2014-01
Logs/{userId}/2014-01-20

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Read(int userId, string date = null)
{

}
```